# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray from Okhttp

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, okhttp

i am trying to get json from server and place it into my RecyclerView, but its says "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray". I am try to track my json, but its shown nothing. Whats wrong, how can i solve this?

```
     private void Prosesdataserver(int id){
     AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        try{
           RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("username_krm", username).add("password_krm", password).build();
           Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://" + urlpakai + "/utrapos/index.php/getpenawaran?id="+integers[0]).post(formBody).build();
           response = client.newCall(request).execute();
           ini = response.body().toString();
           JSONArray array = new JSONArray(ini);
           System.out.println("Saya Berkata: " + ini);
              for(int i=0; i<array.length();i++){
                 JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                 DataJson hasil = new DataJson(object.getInt("id"), object.getString("kode"), object.getString("tglpenawaran"), object.getString("nama"), object.getString("supplier"), object.getString("nopenawaran"));
                 data.add(hasil);
              }
            }catch (IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
             }
             catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
  return null;
 }
```

Comment: Upload the String too that you are trying to convert to JSON

Comment: post your `json` here

Comment: @AxelH, i am using codeigniter for my url.

Comment: @DennyKurniawan have you checked the request ? Are you getting a JSON (check with a REST client )? If so, it is not formatted like a JSON (like the error says)

Comment: Try to use postman to check your response

Comment: @AxelH, yes i am get the json from postman tool, and thats is valid json.

Comment: Well, where is it ? Without a [mcve] it takes more time to find the problem. Valid for you or valid from an online tool ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With minimum information you've shared, I'm assuming the error is at this line

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(ini);
```

The reason behind that is your `ini`. It should be

```
ini = response.body().string();
```

and not `.toString()`

Here is a sample code:

```
try {
        String responseData = response.body().string();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(responseData);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }
```

For more understanding on how to make network calls with OkHttp, take a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-OkHttp).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to .string() part. I also made a typo with toString() and there getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

add fulltext on your database :

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD FULLTEXT(kode,tglpenawaran,nama,supplier,nopenawaran);
```

Then make a test :

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE MATCH (kode,tglpenawaran,nama,supplier,nopenawaran) AGAINST ('text')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line **ini = response.body().toString();**

to

```
ini = response.body().string();
```